# Is a react-bootstrap column not a flex item?

Tags: bootstrap-4, react-bootstrap

I found something weird while working with react-bootstrap. I have nested rows in columns, but I realised that it's impossible to make one of the rows fill up all available space in the column (essentially flex-grow:1) because Col of react-bootstrap is not a flex item. Does anyone know what the best practice in this case is? Is it to add display: flex to the column so that behaves like a flex item, or make all the "intermediate" layers in the grid Rows (either horizontal or vertical) and only use Cols as the last layer?

I've tried that both the solutions I've listed work, I'm just trying to write neat code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes that's true, `Col` component in React-Bootstrap is not a `flex` item, So if you want to make one of the rows fill up all available space in the column, you can add `display: flex` to the `Col` or use `Row` components as the intermediate layers in the grid and only use `Col` components as the last layer.

Both solutions are valid and will work, so the choice ultimately depends on your personal preference and the structure of your code. If you want to keep your code clean and organized, using `Row` components as the intermediate layers may be a better choice, as it makes the structure of your grid more explicit and easier to read. However, if you prefer to keep the number of nested components to a minimum, adding `display: flex` to the `Col` may be a better option.

Another possible solution to consider is to use the `flex` prop provided by `React-Bootstrap` to set the `flex` properties of the `Col`. For example, you can set the `flex` prop to 1 to make the `Col` fill up all available space: `<Col flex={1}>Column 2</Col>`, This can be a cleaner and more concise solution than using `display: flex` or adding Row components.